# FileMaker script executed from web viewer via XML on click event causing web viewer refresh

Tags: javascript, xml, filemaker

I am building a filemaker app that will be used in web direct only. There is a custom web map displayed in a web viewer window. I have written javascript that passes a parameter into a filemaker script (and executes it) via an XML URL based on where the user clicks on the map.

Everything is working fine, except that whenever the test script executes, the web map in the web viewer refreshes.  I know that it is something in FileMaker (not in the JS/HTML of the web map) that is causing the refresh, because when I try executing the script by clicking the map on its own in a browser window (NOT in web direct/web viewer) it executes the script and does not refresh.

The script is very simple - just ( Set Field [Maps::SegId; Get ( ScriptParameter)] ). All it does is take a parameter (from JS via XML) and put it intoa  box in my FileMaker layout. I don't see anything in the script that would cause the refresh either.

Comment: Is the field that you update (Maps::SegId) involved in a calculation which is used for the webviewer. Also, it could be another field which references Maps::SegId and is part of the calculation.

Comment: I thought that too, so I removed the calculation field from the table entirely.  The only calculation going on now is the xml running the script to set the field to the segment ID. The web viewer is still refreshing whenever the script executes. I should emphasize that only the web viewer is refreshing - the rest of the layout is not.

Comment: Try to change the field manually in FileMaker to a different segment id and commit the record. Does this refresh the webviewer?

Comment: No it does not. Only when I execute the script from the web viewer.

Comment: In this case, it is difficult to help without looking the actual file. Try to create a sample file and recreate the problem there, then take it to one of the FileMaker forums, which are better suited to resolve the problems like this.